# Redirect all subdomains to subfolders

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, godaddy, amazon-route53

I'd like to add a rule so that all subdomains get redirected to a subfolder. For example:

```
app1.example.com -> example.com/app1
app2.example.com -> example.com/app2
something.example.com -> example.com/something
```

All subdomains will only be one level deep.

**Questions**

- Which DNS providers allow me to do this?
- Are these alternatives feasible?

  - Redirect them all to a special webapp with a static IP that redirects to the proper subfolder. How can I know from which subdomain they came from?
  - Programatically create each rule when I need it. Which DNS providers have API access to add rules? I think Amazon Route 53 might be the answer here.

Comment: Go Daddy does allow for wildcard DNS setup; however the hosting will not work with wildcards.  You will not be able to do this if you host with Go Daddy.

Comment: @Mike_GoDaddy Thanks for the quick answer! I could look for another provider if it's not possible with GoDaddy. I edited the question.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: What type od redirection are you talking about ? I guess web traffic ? If so you will need to use some rules on the web server too, such as `.htaccess` from apache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which DNS providers allow me to do this?

All competent ones. It doesn't even need to be a DNS-specific providing, most good hosts will help you with this too. There are two stages:

1. A DNS entry is added for `*.example.com`
2. The host's web server (e.g. Apache) is setup to respond to `*.example.com` by routing it to `example.com`'s `VirtualHost`.

Then, at your end, you add a `.htaccess` entry that uses a `RewriteRule` to catch each subdomain, and redirect it to a folder using the `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Untested, but something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^[^.]+\.example\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(.*)   http://example.com/$1/$2
```

Suppose that the user requests `app1.example.com/bob`.

#### Line 2

This will catch `app1.example.com` in the `HTTP_HOST` - it'll match the `RewriteCond`.

#### Line 3

Normally, Apache will only pass `/bob` to be checked against the `RewriteRule`. To use the subdomain, we exploit *Chaining* by forcing the next rule to match

```
${HTTP_HOST}$1
|           ^ /bob
^ app1.example.com
```

#### Line 4

The final `RewriteRule` is now matching against `app1.example.com/bob` and *not* just `/bob`. As a result, it can have a 'full' regular expression to match both this subdomain and the path, and perform the desired redirect.

If you don't want this feature, you can simplify the rules.

---

> Are these alternatives feasible? Redirect them all to a special webapp
>   with a static IP that redirects to the proper subfolder. How can I
>   know from which subdomain they came from?

There is no sure-fire way of doing this. You *could* try the HTTP Referer, but it's not *always* sent by all browsers, some firewalls remove the header, etc.

> Programatically create each rule when I need it. Which DNS providers
>   have API access to add rules? I think Amazon Route 53 might be the
>   answer here.

This would actually result in a *more complex* solution to the above, so I wouldn't recommend it. It would also create a delay: DNS caches would need to update and certain visitors wouldn't be able to use the subdomain immediately until they do. At least with my suggestion above, they'd be able to get going instantly.

Comment: You rock!!! :) Awesome answer. It's crystal clear now. Thanks a lot!